# Add image using WordML

Tags: java, ms-word, wordml

I am trying to add an image into a document using WordML. I have used the xml as a basis from the jpg example from here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/WordML.aspx. I have managed to write Java which creates this exact xml(wordML) in the document, however when I try and open the generated file in MS Word 2007 it says the file in invalid or corrupt.

The xml for the document that won't open is here:

http://pastebin.com/RNEkbvYG (Raw xml)
Sorry for the long paste, this is the shortest example I could create, there's load of gumph at the top and bottom, but you can clearly see the data image in the middle.

http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=RNEkbvYG (download, rename from txt to xml and open with word)

I would greatly appreciate if anybody could look at the xml at the link above and see if they can see why it won't open in word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<w:pict>
            <w:binData w:name="wordml://02000001.jpg">/9j/4AA..Xof/9k=</w:binData>
            <v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" style="width:100%;height:auto" type="#_x0000_t75">
              <v:imagedata o:title="network" src="wordml://02000001.jpg"/>
            </v:shape>
          </w:pict>
```

is 2003 WordML.  There is no w:binData element in the 2007 docx format / ECMA standard.

You might try docx4j instead :-)

See http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/AddImage.java

Comment: Thanks alot for that I have now got an image in my document :)

I have now got another issue, I have a document that I load in and want to replace a specific bit of text with the image. I have had a look at the api and can't find a method like findAnElementById type method or even loop through all the elements and manually search for the text (this is how we have done straight text replacements just using the w3c Document class). Are these types of methods available or is there an easier way to say replace this text with this image?

Thanks
Daniel Lees

Comment: There is no findAnElementById because paragraphs in docx don't generally have IDs.  You can use getJAXBNodesViaXPath, or you could consider using a picture content control. See for example http://dev.plutext.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=634

Comment: I have managed to find the element I want using getJAXBNodesViaXPath, I have a text element which has a value of photo. I now want to add the photo in the place where is text is, my idea was to set the text of the current not to be "" to remove the text photo then get the parent of the text node and add the photo to the parent. Is what I am trying to do possible? (I